# C# 8 understanding await using syntax

Tags: c#, async-await, resharper, using, c#-8.0

I have next method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Quote>> GetQuotesAsync()
{
    using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

    var allQuotes = await connection.QueryAsync<Quote>(@"SELECT [Symbol], [Bid], [Ask], [Digits] FROM [QuoteEngine].[RealtimeData]");

    return allQuotes;
}
```

Everything fine and clear, connection will be disposed at the end of scope.

But resharper suggests to change it to:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Quote>> GetQuotesAsync()
{
    await using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

    var allQuotes = await connection.QueryAsync<Quote>(@"SELECT [Symbol], [Bid], [Ask], [Digits] FROM [QuoteEngine].[RealtimeData]");

    return allQuotes;
}
```

It adds await before using and code is compiled successfully. What does it mean and when do we need to do that?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Similar as `using (...)` uses `IDisposable` to clean up resources, `await using (...)` uses [IAsyncDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0).
This allows to perform also time-consuming tasks (e.g involving I/O) on cleanup without blocking.

Comment: what is the consequence of using `using` when I could use `await using`?

Comment: `using` will call `Dispose()` rather than `await DisposeAsync()` and therefore unneccesarily block the current thread for some time. It depends on the type of object how undesirable the difference is.

Answer (score 37):

If `SqlConnection` implements `IAsyncDisposable` interface, Resharper suggests you to switch to `await using` to dispose it asynchronously using `DisposeAsync` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable?view=netcore-3.1#implementing-iasyncdisposable)

```cs
public interface IAsyncDisposable
{
    ValueTask DisposeAsync();
}
```