# Large Fileupload to Azure with Blob Storage with BlobContainerClient

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, topshelf

I want to upload large Files to Azure Blob Storage (500-2000MB) and I try to do this with the following code:

```
private BlobContainerClient containerClient;    
public async Task<UploadResultDto> Upload(FileInfo fileInfo, string remotePath)
        {
            try
            {
                var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(remotePath + "/" + fileInfo.Name);

                var transferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
                {
                    MaximumConcurrency = 1,
                    MaximumTransferSize = 10485760,
                    InitialTransferSize = 10485760
                };

                await using var uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(fileInfo.FullName);
                
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, transferOptions: transferOptions);
                uploadFileStream.Close();

                return new UploadResultDto()
                {
                    UploadSuccessfull = true
                };

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex,$"Error while uploading File {fileInfo.FullName}");
            }

            return new UploadResultDto()
            {
                UploadSuccessfull = false
            };
        }
```

I instantly get the following message:

```
The specified blob or block content is invalid.
RequestId:c5c2d925-701e-0035-7ce0-8691a6000000
Time:2020-09-09T19:33:40.9559646Z
Status: 400 (The specified blob or block content is invalid.)
```

If i remove the `InitialTransferSize` from the `StorageTransferOptions`, i get the following error after some time:

```
retry failed after 6 tries. (The operation was canceled.)
```

As far as I understood the new SDK, the upload in chunks and therefore the whole handling of the blockIds etc. should be done by the SDK. Or am I wrong?

Does anybody know why this is not working? I did not find anything different then this for BlobContainerClient, only for the old cloudblobcontainer.

**Update:**
Some Additional Informations:

It is a .netCore 3.1 Application which runs with the library Topshelf as a Windows Service

Comment: what is this? `await using var uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(fileInfo.FullName);` Is that some new thing in C# that I am not aware of?

Comment: @Andy https://stackoverflow.com/a/58792016/765766

Comment: Whoa sweet. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I ran into this "Retry failed after 6 tries. A task was canceled." trying to export a 3GB Azure SQL database into Azure storage. Worked for many years w/ no problems until this month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get it working with version 12.6.0...

I downgraded to Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob v11 and implemented the upload based on this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58741171/765766

This works fine for me now

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your question after you remove the `InitialTransferSize` from the `StorageTransferOptions` is similar to the issue [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62736604/1879019).

You may be able to resolve the issue by setting the timeouts for the blob client as follows:

```cs
var blobClientOptions = new BlobClientOptions
{
    Transport = new HttpClientTransport(new HttpClient { Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan }),
    Retry = { NetworkTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan }
};
```

`InfiniteTimeSpan` is probably overkill, but at least it will prove if that was the issue.

Those settings got rid of the "retry failed after 6 tries" error for me and got the upload when I started using the `Azure.Storage.Blobs` v12.8.0 package

Answer (score 0):

I create a new console app and test with your code which works very well.

1.Confirm that you do not have [inconsistencies in assemblies](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/14124). Remove the earlier version of `Azure.Storage.Blobs` and update you it[to the latest version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/11503).

And why your `containerClient` is **private**? You could set it in `Upload` method with following code:

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionstring);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("containerName");
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(remotePath + "/" +fileInfo.Name);
```

Comment: I have the latest Version (12.6.0) of Azure.Storage.Blobs installed, I also cleaned and reinstalled everything again. Still the same error
The containerClient is initialized in the constructor, so that I do not need to initialize it in every method that needs it.