# 'await' on left side of assigment

Tags: c#

I was looking at some of the example code on [Microsoft Playwright](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro/) and in the example code, there is this bit

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
    await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync();
    var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
    await page.GotoAsync("https://playwright.dev/dotnet");
    await page.ScreenshotAsync(new PageScreenshotOptions { Path = "screenshot.png" });
}
```

What does the first `await` in line 4 do? I've tried searching for it but I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: The `await using` syntax means the disposal uses `DisposeAsync` instead of `Dispose`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# 8 understanding await using syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791938/c-sharp-8-understanding-await-using-syntax)

Comment: There's not really an await on the left side of the assignment. You could split this up into two lines for clarity `var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync();` and then `await using browser;`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content ([under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about:

```
await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync();
```

line, then this is not just an assignment but two features added in C# 8 combined - [asynchronous disposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#asynchronous-disposable):

> Starting with C# 8.0, the language supports asynchronous disposable types that implement the `System.IAsyncDisposable` interface. You use the `await using` statement to work with an asynchronously disposable object.

and [using declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations):

> A using declaration is a variable declaration preceded by the `using keyword`. It tells the compiler that the variable being declared should be disposed at the end of the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await#asynchronous-streams-and-disposables):

> You use the `await using` statement to work with an asynchronously disposable object, that is, an object of a type that implements an [`IAsyncDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable?view=net-6.0) interface. For more information, see the [Using async disposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync#using-async-disposable) section of the Implement a `DisposeAsync` method article.

`IAsyncDisposable` is used for releasing unmanaged resources in asynchronous manner.